# MySQL COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have a table (details) that looks like this

id | seed | lastChecked | reporter

I would like to make a query to get all the id that where checked in the last hour and group them by reporter to know if one reporter is down or not working properly.

This is what i have found so far:

```
    SELECT * FROM `details`
    WHERE `details`.lastChecked > date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour)
    GROUP BY `reporter`;
```

I'd like to get like:

```
reporter_1 | 16 seed modified
```

or something similar.

I'll keep on looking at all the function.

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that

```
SELECT `reporter`, count(*)
FROM `details`
WHERE `details`.lastChecked > date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour)
GROUP BY `reporter`
```

HTH